# How to open a link in same window with minimized frame?

Tags: hyperlink, target

How to open a `link` in same window with minimized frame?
To open a `link` in same window there is a attribute target with value `"_parent"`. But I want to know that how to open a `link` in same window with minimized or custom frame ?

Thank you to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked this question as a beginner, I've the solution now for future beginner readers.
To open a link in same window with minimized frame, there is a tag in html called `<iframe>` is used,

**Example**

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can use the height and width attributes to specify the size of the iframe:</p>

<iframe src="https://www.google.co.in/" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```